# Can weakness of gravity explore new dimensions?

Tags: forces, gravity, spacetime-dimensions, interactions

Since gravitational force is weakest force out of the four fundamental fources at the microscopic level. Is it possible that gravitational force is strong in a particular direction at a new  microscopic dimension.

Comment: is brane/bulk explanation for weakness of gravity relevant? I.e. gravity propagates the bulk, everything else SM is on the brane

Comment: PS is calling gravity, EW and strong the 'four'ces a new terminology or a typo!? I quite like it!

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea of [brane-world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) approaches to string theory.  I don't know their current state.